# moved a joomla site, error: load error: failed to find error.less and master.less

Tags: joomla, migration

I've just moved a joomla site to a new server, and it is displaying the following error message:

Error displaying the error page: load error: failed to find /home/worldle0/public_html/old/templates/shaper_helix_ii/less/error.less: load error: failed to find /home/worldle0/public_html/old/templates/shaper_helix_ii/less/master.less

The path there is incorrect, but I can't find where it needs to be replaced with the new directory path.

The joomla admin is working fine, but the front page is a white screen with this error.

I've done a search of the template folder, and the joomla folder for instances of this path, but couldn't find it.

Thanks

Comment: You have to enable debug in your Joomla configuration. Change the error to maximum. Paste the output here.

Comment: Thank you for this info, but no other error messages showed when debug was turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article helped me solve the problem:

http://www.nfollmer.com/2014/04/07/moving-a-wordpress-site-with-cherry-framework-lessphp-errors/

I went to this folder and deleted 3 less cache files.

/cache/com_templates/templates/shaper_helix_ii

Comment: Glad I could help Crystal - Thanks for sharing the link!

Answer (score 2):

In my site also i got this same error
Please do the following steps it will resolve

**Setp 1:**

```
Delete 3 less cache files
```

If this not work means go to step 2

**Step 2:**

```
Edit the path old into new path the following 3 files
1.preset1.css.cache
2.template.css.cache
3.error.css.cache
```

Or this not work means go stept 3

**Step 3:**

```
Go to administrative panel and delete the cache and expired cache.
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down into steps. I tried Step 3 first.
I want to add that this worked for the same problem on a Joomla! 3 site with Helix builder.